# CSS gets broken when minimizing

Tags: css, minify, pseudo-element

I have a website, where we are using a tool to minimize and compress css code. It is called JCH, it is a plugin for Joomla, I think you can use it on Drupal too. I have an issue this css code:

```
#sp-user3 .help-menu .nav.menu :not(.user-menu){
display: inline-flex;
}
```

It is being converted to:

```
#sp-user3 .help-menu .nav.menu:not(.user-menu){display:inline-flex}
```

As you can see ".nav.menu :not" is converted to ".nav.menu:not" which causes the css rule to not be applied as intended.

This can be an error on the tool. How can i rewrite it or add a character to avoid that confusion? any ideas are welcome.

Comment: The CSS standard will say you can use >> for the descendant combinator; this will allow you to write `.nav.menu>>:not` instead of `.nav.menu :not`. Doesn't currently work in any browser though, so that's not the answer.

Comment: You could try `.nav.menu *:not` (with an asterisk), but I don't have the minimiser here, so I can't check if that will work.

Comment: @MrLister I will try it.

Comment: yes, I think that too. One question ":not(.user-menu)" is referring to any tag inside the  tag having the class ".nav and .menu" right? or does it refer to the same tag which has "nav.menu"? (I did not write that css rule) @MrLister

Comment: @Eduardo Yes, any element not having class "user-menu" inside any element having classes "nav" and "menu". They're called elements by the way, not tags.

Comment: @MrLister your solution worked, can you post an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug, and this is not the first time I encountered it.

The StackSnippet editor on this site used to have the very same bug in its Tidy button. See my [bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309573/1016716). It was fixed soon after.

So you can file a bug report with JCH and then wait for it to be fixed as well.

Meanwhile, you can insert a `*` before the `:` in the CSS as a workaround.
`:not()` is a shorthand for `*:not()` anyway, so you won't be changing the meaning of the selector, just writing out in full what was implied.

Answer (score 1):

It's a definitely tool issue, web minifiers like [Minify](http://www.minifier.org/) generating correct code.

```
#sp-user3 .help-menu .nav.menu :not(.user-menu){display:inline-flex}
```

Comment: yes, I think that too. One question ":not(.user-menu)" is referring to any tag inside the  tag having the class ".nav and .menu" right? or does it refer to the same tag which has "nav.menu"? (I did not write that css rule)

Comment: CSS rule above means *display:inline-flex* for classes: *help-menu*, *nav menu* and not for *user-menu*.